# How can I prevent deleted file come back when merge branch on Git

Tags: git

I have branch "develop_refactor", base on "develop" branch. In "develop_refactor", I deleted some file in "develop_refactor". Sometimes, I merge from "develop" to "develop_refactor" to update newest code from "develop". But deleted file is come back. I have to delete again. How can I prevent it return ?

**Update**:

[image]

Comment: If I understand this correctly, you have two branches.  develop_refactor is a branch "ahead" of develop branch.  However, you are merging develop into develop_refactor?  Is this correct?

Comment: are you sure of removing the object from git context rather than just from local?

Comment: @elaijuh Oh, I'm sorry. This is my mistake. It return because some one edit it in this file in "developer". So, it appear in unstage with conflict icon. And I resolve by check it. And it return.
Other deleted file, if it not conflict, it will not come back.

Comment: @Carlise: I update picture for you

Answer (score 2):

For that reason, the proper way to keep a branch updated is through rebasing.

`$ git rebase develop`

This will replay all of develop_refactor's commits *on top of* develop's latest commits - thereby making sure the file is deleted every time.

Answer (score 0):

Deleted file will appear when it conflict with file in server. You are delete it, but some one is modify it on server. So git detect it as a conflict. And it restore again for you decide. If you don't want this file, simply remove it.

If deleted file not modify by other person, it will not appear again when you merge from developer to sub branch.